# ASP.NET web api and knockout js viewmodel data not binding from client to server

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a problem with posting data from a jquery ajax post to an asp.net web api method. The date properties are shown in the web console surrounded by two double quotes then get reset and the boolean properties are being set to null.

Javascript:

```
self.startTime = ko.observable(startTime); 
    self.startTimeDate = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return moment(self.startTime()).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:ss");
        },
        write: function(value){
            self.startTime(moment(value).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:ss"));
        }
    });

    self.endTime = ko.observable(endTime); 
    self.endTimeDate = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return moment(self.endTime()).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:ss");
        },
        write: function (value) {
            self.endTime(moment(value).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:ss"));
        }
    });



self.includeDeviceAddedToInventory = ko.observable(true); 
var model = {
            auditLogType: ko.toJSON(self.auditLogType),
            id: ko.toJSON(self.auditLogId),
                entriesPerPage: ko.toJSON(self.entriesPerPage), 
                    pageNumber: ko.toJSON(self.pageNumber), 
                startTime: ko.toJSON(self.startTimeDate), 
                    endTime: ko.toJSON(self.endTimeDate), 
                    includeDeviceAddedToInventory: ko.toJSON(self.includeDeviceAddedToInventory) 

...

$.post("api/AuditLog", { filterInfo: model })
```

---

The javascript console shows the objects as:

entriesPerPage: "0",
pageNumber: "0",
endTime: ""10-01-2014 06:10:00"",
startTime: ""10-01-2014 06:10:00"",
includeDeviceAddedToInventory: "true"

However the .net debugger shows the objects as: 
entriesPerPage: 0,
pageNumber: 0,
endTime: {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM},
startTime: {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM},
null

ASP.NET

```
public class PostModel
    {
public int EntriesPerPage { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public string IncludeDeviceAddedToInventory { get; set; }
}

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(PostModel filterInfo)
            {
```

I've attempted to serialize with a newtonsoft web api attribute which hasn't worked. The syntax may have been incorrect though. Could anyone please post samples or help?

Thank you.

Comment: Your javascript console output shows doubled up quotes around the date.  Is that really how it is, or a typo?

Comment: That's how the date really is appearing.

Comment: then that would explain why its coming in as a default date.  I would imagine it thinks your passing an empty string (and generally messing up your parameter list)

Answer (score 0):

`ko.toJSON` (and the underlying `JSON.stringify`) applied to a string will enclose it in double quotes (they will be part of the result):

```
ko.toJSON("aaa") = "\"aaa\""
```

When a member of an object is a result of `ko.toJSON` and that object is serialized to JSON also (when sent to server), you will have these extra quotes also. The solution is simple, do not serialize the properties separately, create the object with the real values and send it, it will be serialized as a whole:

```
var model = {
    auditLogType: self.auditLogType,
    id: self.auditLogId,
    entriesPerPage: self.entriesPerPage, 
    pageNumber: self.pageNumber, 
    startTime: self.startTimeDate, 
    endTime: self.endTimeDate, 
    includeDeviceAddedToInventory: self.includeDeviceAddedToInventory 

...

$.post("api/AuditLog", { filterInfo: model })
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is not working for me though, I still see the objects shown the same.

Comment: You can see here ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c50rm2dL/2/)) the results of serializing an object with an already serialized property and one with a raw property.

Comment: Thank you for the sample, it doesn't however use any observables. This is what makes using ko.toJSON necessary in the script I'm working with. filterInfo: ko.toJSON(model) and filterInfo: model in my initial post display the same results in .net webapi.